# Adding a class to fb:comment-count

Tags: facebook, comments

I'd like to add a class to fb:comment-count (without using a div). I noticed when using web inspector there appears to be a blank class assignment by default. I was wondering if anyone knew how to add a class into this field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have control over what classes Facebook renders when using their FBML tags.  You should be able to apply styling to the `fb_comments_count` class though in your css file or wrap the tag in a div and style that div.

Comment: Does it automatically create a fb_comments_count class? I didn't notice it in the code when I looked through it, although my familiarity with the Facebook API is rather slim.

Comment: Ok - this kind of worked. I was able to get the 0 comments to work, since it assigns it a class of `fb_comments_count_zero`. The ones with a count, however, do not have a class assigned to them.

I've tried sticking it in a div, but it refuses to take any styling. Any suggestions?